# Is there any code to do that my Discordbot (discord.js) only work at one Server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am coding right now with node / discord.js
And is there any code that does that the bot only work at one server?
If yes please send me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont want the bot to be added to other peoples server just make sure that it is set in discord dev portal to be a private bot. You could also do a simple check on messages

```js
const myServer = (put your discord server id here);

bot.on('message', msg => {
   if(msg.guild.id != myServer){
      return;
   }
});
```